# Bootstrap-vue connect to vue.js but it's not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, console, console.log, bootstrap-vue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6tsv.png)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at eval (config.js?228e:6)
at Module../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/utils/config.js (chunk-vendors.js:6778)
at **webpack_require** (app.js:849)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (props.js?cf75:1)
at Module../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/utils/props.js (chunk-vendors.js:7054)
at **webpack_require** (app.js:849)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (model.js?58f2:1)
at Module../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/utils/model.js (chunk-vendors.js:6970)

I think it's connect with npm console:

warning  in ./src/plugins/bootstrap-vue.js

"export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

warning  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js

"export 'default' (reexported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

Comment: connect bootstrap-vue to vue cli

Comment: how to fix that? help please

Comment: can you share your `main.js` or `index.js` file content?

Comment: //main.js                                                                                                                             import './plugins/bootstrap-vue'
import '@babel/polyfill'
import 'mutationobserver-shim'
import './plugins/bootstrap-vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')

Comment: Have you tried importing Bootstrap-vue like so `import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'` & then passing it in `use()` method like so `Vue.use(BootstrapVue)`? in the `main.js` or `app.js` file?

Comment: // this one?                                                                                                                                   import Vue from 'vue'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

Comment: Can you update your answer with the file's content nicely format, please? It'll really help to assist you better.

Comment: Also, which `node`, `Vue` & `Vue CLI` version are you using?

Comment: Bro, if i reinstall bootstrap-vue and creat another new folder, will the program automatically do it with no error?

Comment: C:\Users\ASUS>node -v
v15.8.0

C:\Users\ASUS>vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) in [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) by:

- Running the command `npm i bootstrap-vue` from your project's `root`.
- Import it in your `main.js` file like so:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import { BootstrapVue, BootstrapVueIcons } from 'bootstrap-vue'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons)

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

You should be able to import & use `BootstrapVue`'s components now.